# error NullReferenceException was unhandled at progressbar

Tags: vb.net

```
    Public Sub GetStationDataFromDatabase()

    Dim StationTable As New DataTable
    StationTable.TableName = "Station"


    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim SqlString As String
    Dim OperStaRow As DataRow
    Counter = 0

    ProgressBar.Visible = True
    ProgressBar.Minimum = 1
    ProgressBar.Maximum = LocalDataSet.Tables("OR").Rows.Count
    ProgressBar.Value = 1
    ProgressBar.Step = 1
    For Each OperStaRow In LocalDataSet.Tables("OR").Rows
        SqlString = "JUST SOME STRING HERE"

        ExecuteSqlCommand(SqlString, StationTable)
        ProgressBar.PerformStep()
        ProgressBar.Refresh()
        Counter = Counter + 1

        If Counter Mod 20 = 0 Then
            Application.DoEvents()  
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

so, the error first happpen at progressbar.visible = True. even when i remove it, the error occur the to the line below it. can you tell me what is wrong?

and it happen when user select listbox menu. suppose i have options A and B.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that there is a typo with progressbar object name. pls check spellings. there is nothing wrong in your code.

other than that,
i suggest that you check row count > 0 before assigning progressbar maximum value.

regards

Comment: i did check all of u said above, and all is good. and the problem occurred only when i use listbox1.SelectecItem .  and when i change to listbox1.SelectedValue no errors came out ,  do u know why is that??